# React native navigation call function on navigation.goBack()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

Hi all So I am still learning React Native Navigation and I am trying to call a function when the user goes back to a navigation. So I have 2 screens. A home page and a Detailed page. You initially see the Home page and once you click on a component you will see the detail page. Once you are done you click back which is:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{ position: "absolute", top: 35, left: 12, zIndex: 999 }}>
     <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-back" size={35} color="white" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The issue is, when the person clicks on the `TouchableOpacity` they go back to the Home page but I want to call an update function or even the `componentDidMount` function. How can I do this?

I tries this but it did not work:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', {
      onGoBack: () => this.myFunction(),
    });
```

This is when the person is on the Home page and they click on the component to go to the Detail page but it still does not work?

Any suggestions? Thank you for any input

Comment: put it in `componentDidAppear`, ref: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/screen-lifecycle

Comment: Or you could try [this.](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/issues/191#issuecomment-417972354)

Comment: can you show code you call myFunction in detail

Comment: @AnhDevit its not anything special really, its just a function that has console.log("HERE")

Comment: With me I will use context or redux to update data